# Listener to catch all ajax responds coming from server

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to catch all ajax responds coming from the server side ? Actually I have an enterprise application in which I need for a curtain reason to apply some functionality  in all server responds.

Example:

In all my pages, I am sending the ajax request to the server in this way:

```
    $.getJSON("server.php", {
        fn: "get"
    }, function (json) {
       if(json['success']){
         // 
       }else {
         //
       }
    });
```

Comment: It's *well-worth* your time to just read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It takes an hour, two hours at the most, and saves you no end of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They're called jQuery [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), from which you can hook into different stages of all AJAX requests/responses.

For example:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    // do something
});
```